# RS232-to-Ethernet adapter configuration not working

Tags: networking, windows-10, terminal, ethernet, rs232

I have a iPocket232 serial RS-232 to Ethernet adapter and whenever I try to configure the settings in a terminal window on Windows 10, it doesn't let me select an option. When I type in an option number and hit enter, nothing happens. I contacted iPocket232.com support but their response was useless. I have the latest firmware on the device and have tried several different terminals including PuTTY, ZOC Terminal, and HyperTerminal.

The adapter is connected with a RS232-to-USB cable to the PC. The terminal-emulators have the 8-n-1 configuration (9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit) and it's connected to COM1. The user guide (bit.ly/2rV1C3D) does not give a solution to my problem.

**Update:**

Thanks to @sawdust, I found that setting the flow control to "none" and switching the serial-to-USB cable that connects the adapter to the PC fixes the problem.

Comment: *"their response was useless"* -- You have to do a better job of describing what you have tried so far.  How are you connecting this adapter to your Windows 10 PC?  You mention nothing about how you have configured the terminal-emulation programs.  You fail to mention whether you have read and followed the instructions from the user guide.

Comment: @sawdust The adapter is connected with a RS232-to-USB cable to the PC. The terminal-emulators have the 8-n-1 configuration (9600 baud, 8 data bits, no parity, and 1 stop bit) and it's connected to COM1. The user guide (http://bit.ly/2rV1C3D) does not give a solution to my problem.

Comment: What about flow-control?  So the troubleshooting section in the user guide is in your opinion worthless?  Have you used a break-out box or oscilloscope to verify that your cables are good?  Your responses should be part of you post rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sawdust, I found that setting the flow control to "none" and switching the serial-to-USB cable that connects the adapter to the PC fixes the problem.